# How to create (graphical) calculation view on HANA via jdbc

Tags: jdbc, data-modeling, hana

As far as I know in the latest HANA version (2 SPS00) graphical calculation views replaced (SQL) scripted calculation views as well as attribute views and analytical views.

Graphical calculation views are design time artifacts which gets some kind of compiled to a runtime artifact (a view) in the HANA catalog which than can be queried via SQL like a regular view.

But how can I create such calculation views programmatically via for instance JDBC. There must be a reason why they are "graphical" in favor of SQL `CREATE VIEW xyz...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytical views, attribute views and scripted calc. views have been deprecated to reduce the number of development artefact types. The functionality has been included in the general calculation view.
The main benefit of graphical views over SQL commands is that, depending on the scenario, the graphical views are easier and quicker to develop and understand. 
They should give developers who are not as comfortable with SQL an easy way to build information models.

Concerning the option to create graphical views via SQL: although possible, this option is not available for developers outside SAP.

Comment: So graphical calculation vies can't be created via API like JDBC for third party developers at all?

Comment: Nope. I'm nosy aware of any 3rd party option for that being supported by SAP.

Comment: To say it politely, this is very sad by SAP to deprecate all other options and don't provide any support for 3rd party devs via API

Comment: There hadn't been an option for creating any of the deprecated information view types via JDBC/SQL so what's your point?

Comment: Even worse... My point is that all the nice benefits of HANA are useless since you can't create/access it in your application

Comment: If creating HANA specific development artifacts is the only thing your application should do you're right. Most users seem to want to use it for data processing though, so I guess that's alright.

Comment: Still for "data processing" someone needs create the data model (aka development artifacts like calculation views) to store the data to be processed. If I get it right this someone needs to be an SAP application

Comment: HANA comes with all the tooling for developers to create the development artifacts. So, the IDE is bundled. With HANA studio and the Webbased IDE you can create all dev. artifacts. Also, you can create runtime objects via SQL and run complex SQL statements. But hey, if you're not happy about that SAP didn't open every option via open APIs than that's your right, too.

Comment: I'm aware of the variety of HANA Dev tools and quite a big fan of Eclipse-based HANA Studio rather than the WebIDE, but still from a 3rd party application point of view this does not help. Thanks for giving much details about the topic even if I'm not satisfied with the current situation.